# How to execute promises in batches (first resolving 10, then next 10 and so on)

Tags: javascript

Please find below the code I have written. As you can see, there is a function called waitForPromiseChunkToBeResolved which logs *Waiting for the batch to be resolved*, resolves an array of promises, and then finally logs *The batch has been all resolved*. (The program starts with the *main()* function.)

Each batch of promises should take 2 seconds (as this is what I hard-coded via setTimeout, see *promiseTakes2000ms*). The program currently takes around 2 seconds in total, as it executes all 40 promises in parallel - but what I want to achieve is that it first executes 10 promises, then the next 10, and so on. So the program should take around 8 seconds (with an array of 40 promises executing 4 chunks of 10 promises each).

I have tried using 3rd party libraries like the npmjs packages async and p-queue.

```js
const promiseTakes2000ms = (succeeds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (succeeds) {
                resolve("Success / 2000ms wait")
            } else {
                reject("Failure / 2000ms wait")
            }
        }, 2000)
    })
}

const reflectPromise = (promise) => {
    return promise.then((promiseResult) => {
        return {
            promiseResult,
            success: true
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
            return {
                error,
                success: false
            }
    })
}

const sliceArrayIntoChunks = (arr, chunkSize) => {
    const chunks = []
    let i = 0
    const n = arr.length

    while (i < n) {
      chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += chunkSize))
    }

    return chunks
}

const waitForPromiseChunkToBeResolved = (promiseChunk) => {
    console.log("=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved")
    return Promise.all(promiseChunk).then((resolvedChunkResults) => {
        console.log(resolvedChunkResults)
        console.log("*** The batch has been all resolved")
        return resolvedChunkResults
    })
}


const executePromisesBatchAfterBatch = async (promises) => {
    const promisesReflected = promises.map(reflectPromise)
    const manyPromisesInChunksOfTen = sliceArrayIntoChunks(promisesReflected, 10)
    const waitForAllPromiseChunks = manyPromisesInChunksOfTen.map(async (batch) => {
        await waitForPromiseChunkToBeResolved(batch)
    })
    await Promise.all(waitForAllPromiseChunks)
}

const main = async () => {
    const resolvingPromises = new Array(20).fill(promiseTakes2000ms(true))
    const rejectingPromises = new Array(20).fill(promiseTakes2000ms(false))
    const manyPromises = resolvingPromises.concat(rejectingPromises)
    await executePromisesBatchAfterBatch(manyPromises)
}

main()
```

I expect the program to take 8 seconds and to output the following:

```
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
[ { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
[ { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
[ { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
[ { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
```

But the current, incorrect output is:

```
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
=== Waiting for the batch to be resolved
[ { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
[ { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true },
  { promiseResult: 'Success / 2000ms wait', success: true } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
[ { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
[ { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false },
  { error: 'Failure / 2000ms wait', success: false } ]
*** The batch has been all resolved
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute all chunks in parallel here:

```
 const waitForAllPromiseChunks = manyPromisesInChunksOfTen.map(async (batch) => {
    await waitForPromiseChunkToBeResolved(batch)
})
```

Instead, just loop one after another:

```
 const results = [];

  for(const batch of manyPromisesInChunksOfTen)
    results.push(...await waitForPromiseChunkToBeResolved(batch));

 return results;
```